# How to construct a full-text search predicate for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I want to search a full-text column for the following two terms:

```
2011
J Vineyards
```

where I construct the predicate as

```
"2011*" and "j vineyards*"
```

no rows are returned.

A record which should match is

```
2011 j vineyards viognier alexander valley united states
```

After experimentation, it seems to be related to the single "j" character.

EDIT:

Here is the select statement for the full-text column BeverageSearchData.

```
Declare @test nvarchar(100);
Set @test='""2011*" and "j vineyards*"';
Select * from bv_beverage WHERE CONTAINS (BeverageSearchData,@test)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of possibilities going on here.  The full query and not just the predicate would help you get a better answer.

One thing that is probably going on is that SQL Full-text search eliminates single characters (As in J) when building its index.

If using `CONTAINS`, you may need to change your noise file and restart the SQL Server FullText Search service.

If using `LIKE`, you may be able try adding an additional single character wildcard.  Play with it and see if it works without the 2011 and then add it back in.

```
WHERE myColumn like 'j_vineyards%'
WHERE myColumn like 'j%vineyards%'
```

An additional thing to note is that `CONTAINS` does not supports leading wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `%`, not `*`.

Try this instead:

```
"%2011%" and "%j vineyards%"
```

Comment: Why does "%2011%" and "%j%" not return any rows?

Answer (score 0):

What language did you choose when creating the index? SQL Server associates the system full-text stoplist by default when [creating an index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) which is probably what is happening in your case.

Try building the index with STOPLIST OFF like so -

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX on [table]([column]) ON [catalog] WITH STOPLIST OFF;
```

Alternatively, you can [modify the stoplists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx) to exclude certain words such as 'j' in the example shown above.